# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connection()

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I am using PHP 7 and using mssql as a database.

I have an error that tells me that:

> `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connection()`

I didn't know what to download for extension and I'm not sure if I will put it in `php.ini`. pls help

Comment: try `odbc_connect()`  instead of `odbc_connection()`

Comment: HI this is mine $connection = odbc_connect('test','rsm','password123'); i already copied the extension of extension=php_odbc.dll but it still doesnt work